# GEE - convert a FeatureCollection asset into Features

Tags: google-earth-engine

I need to extract the spectral signature from many ROIs defined by polygons. Polygons are `Features` because store a numeric value as ID. Instead of creating every `Feature` manually, I have uploaded a
shapefile containing the polygons and the attribute as an asset, and it is read as a `FeatureCollection`:

[image]

If I use `ui.Chart.image.regions` and the imported asset, GEE plots the chart correctly, one chart for all the spectral signatures. However, every spectral signature is labelled as "undefined", while every line of the chart should be labelled by its own ID attribute.

[image]

When I create `Features` manually instead, I can set the label and get something like this:

```
var2 = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Feature(
        ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [[[-81.3841725473454, 28.290378077261185],
              [-81.3841725473454, 28.289876669879202],
              [-81.38360566782504, 28.289876669879202],
              [-81.38360566782504, 28.290378077261185]]], null, false),
        {
          "label": "var2",
          "system:index": "0"
        }),
var3 = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Feature(
        ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [[[-81.38177280884001, 28.288828895937563],
              [-81.38177280884001, 28.28832537789612],
              [-81.3812034911887, 28.28832537789612],
              [-81.3812034911887, 28.288828895937563]]], null, false),
        {
          "label": "var3",
          "system:index": "0"
        });
```

The properties stored in the `Features` are values in the attribute table of the shapefile (field: label, value: var2, var3...).

Is there a way to get the same results using an imported asset?

Comment: the question is not clear to me, do you want each Feature to be a variable? why? maybe if you explain what you are trying to do we could guide you better

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe, thanks for your comment. Yes I would like to have every polygon from the imput asset be a distinct Feature variable to extract the spectral signature of the pixels covered by the polygons and to plot them in a chart as distinct curves. If I upload a shapefile as an asset I am only able to import it in the workspace as a FeatureCollection that does not support plotting. I can edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests you're trying to do something the wrong way; you should use the collection as much as possible, but if you're trying to e.g.:  make a separate plot for each polygon, then you can access each one by converting the collection to a list and then addressing the list.  This is one of the few places where you'll need to use getInfo to pull the whole collection into the browser.

Also, the plotting tools built into the code editor aren't designed for plotting individual spectra, so you'll probably want to convert the results into an array and so you can do your own styling/options to get something nice.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5e3b9f7820452cd9d4ae772c891be2d7

```
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2").filterBounds(roi).first().select("SR.*")
var samples = l8.sampleRegions(collection).getInfo()

var size = samples.features.length
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  var f = samples.features[i]
  var props = f.properties
  var keys = Object.keys(props)
  var values = []
  for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    values.push(props[keys[j]])
  }
  print(ui.Chart.array.values([keys, values], 1))
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, just a couple of additional info: how to display the attributes of the polygon in the Collection (your charts are all nameless, and with many features it is impossible to know the input feature) and how to plot all the individual spectra in just one chart?

Comment: I have rephrased the entire question, sorry for being inacccurate and thanks for helping me to review the question.